# Passing var from background.js to popup.js

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to send a variable `"word"` from *background.js* to *popup.js* where it will be processed in a function.
The problem is i cannot send that variable and start the *popup.js* in any way.

I tried:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({valoare: word},function atribut(word){}); with and without the function attached.
```

And from what i heard i can access it without a request straight from *popup.js* but nothing is working under *popup.js*.

```
var selection = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().word;
alert(selection);
```

I understand that *popup.js* fires only when i click the page action but nothing happens then.

*Popup.html*:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.googleSuggest.js">
<link class="jsbin" href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="suggest.min.css" />
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" />
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
<div id="pop">
     <label for="term">Suggested term: </label>
     <input id="term" style="display: none;"type="text" value=""/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably need to use `chrome.extension.getViews({type: 'popup'})` from background.js.

Comment: I used that with no success or at least i don't know what form does it returns if i have something like :
`var popups = chrome.extension.getViews({type: "popup"});
   if (popups.length != 0) {
    var popup = popups[0];
    popup.atribut(word);
   };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the variable you want is in the background page, and the popup is only loaded when you open it, you could use [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to do this. In this case it would be best to send a message from the popup to the background page like this:

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:"getWord"},function(response){
  //here response will be the word you want
  console.log(response);
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  if(message.method == "getWord"){
    //depending on how the word is stored you can do this in one of several ways
    // 1. If it is a global variable, we can just return it directly
    sendResponse(word);
    // 2. It needs to be retrieved asynchronously, in that case we do this
    getWord(sendResponse);
    return true;
    // This passes the ability to reply to the function where we get the info
    // Once we have the info we can just use sendResponse(word); like before
  }
});
```

Edit: Okay so I took your code and edited some of it, but the initial "Works!" popup worked without any changes. These will just help prevent problems in the future.

**manifest.json**

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs", "https://twitter.com/*"
],
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["https://twitter.com/*"],
  "js": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "myscript.js"],
  "css": ["mystyle.css" , "jquery-ui.css", "suggest.min.css"]
}],
```

I removed the duplicate permission, and you were trying to inject a css file in the `js` section.

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(msg.check)
    word = msg.check;
  if(msg.method == "getWord")
    sendResponse(word);
});
```

**script.js**

```
//get the word you want to send
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({check: word});
```

You had multiple `onMessage` listeners, I combined them.

With these changes, when clicking the page action, the first popup pops up followed by an empty one as word is never set to anything.

Comment: Thank you for looking over my code, i corrected the bad parts and it still does nothing... I don't understand what is the issue, popup.js never fires.
My alert from the background.js actually works very well :/ Is this weird?

Comment: `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({check: word},function resp(word){});` This is the code i use from myscript.js (the contentscript) and i send the word to the background.js with it. I think it is badly written given the function resp(word){} in it. How may i use it properly?

Comment: What can i do about that function resp ?

Comment: Send the word variable from myscript.js to the background (or straight to the popup.js if possible.

Comment: @Edeph Then you don't need it at all, see the updated code. Note that the response callback is optional.

Comment: And it's send to the background right ? Can i send it straight to the popup.js ? Or background acts like an interface ?

Comment: @Edeph while it is possible to send messages to the popup, it can only receive them while it is open, it is best to store the stuff in the background page as a go between

Comment: It finally worked, thank you very much for your patience and time, you are the kindest!

Comment: @Edeph i am trying to do the same. Can you please help me out. I want to send some data from background.js to popup.js